# calling genericmodel validateAndSave method won't have the record id autogenerated

Tags: model, save, playframework

I have the following code that create/save a user record, the database is the default (H2 in memory) database.

I expect that, after calling validateAndSave (of GenericModel) API on the user instance, the user will have an id autogenerated.

But I am getting a 404 at client side, ie, the code failed on notFoundIfNull in get method.

Is that correct behavior?

```
public static void add(String body) {
    User user = new Gson().fromJson(body, User.class);

    if (User.findBy(user.email) != null) {
        badRequest();
    }

    user.validateAndSave();

    get(user.id);
}

public static void get(Long id) {
    User user = User.findBy(id);

    notFoundIfNull(user);

    render(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if you are passing a null as id to `get`? Most likely you are, as the user you have in memory will have not been refreshed.

If you have to reuse the id try to do this:

```
  user = user.save();
```

I'm not adding validation, as right now you are not doing anything with it. ValidateAndSave (see [code](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/GenericModel.java#L159)) returns true if the validation was ok, false otherwise. You are ignoring it, so no point on using that method.

If you still want to validate, better separate the steps: first validate and then save to obtain the new id.